# Android auto touch macro/script on start-up(no root)

Tags: android, macros, coordinates, tablet

I've installed an android tablet in my car to replace the factory stereo and one thing that annoys me is that after every start there's 4-5 on screen buttons I need to press first in order for the tablet to start streaming music from my phone.
Would anyone have any ideas on how I could create something like a macro/script that would execute after the tablet turns on and simulate a few touches on screen?(I'm assuming with x,y coordinates).
I can't root the tablet by the way

Comment: AFAIK you can't -- by design (because of the possibility of rogue apps hijacking banking apps etc.)

Comment: While unfortunate that does make sense.